# Play framework 2 : What is a proper way to render the contents of parent template?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Normally, when a template uses inheritance, it's possible to render the contents of parent template. For example, in `Twig`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block sidebar %}
    {{ parent() }}
    ...
{% endblock %}
```

It means that if I sometimes don't need the contents of parent template, I just simply remove the `parent()` function. How can I achieve this in `Scala` template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a HTML block in ***child*** view first and then pass it to parent (***layout***):

```
@sidebar = {
    <div>MySidebar</div>
}

@parent(sidebar){
    <div>Main content of the child view</div>
}
```

So in `parent.scala.html` layout you will use it just like

```
@(sidebar: Html = null)(content: Html)

<div id="parent-wrap">
    @sidebar
    @content
</div>
```

Of course if you gonna to use the same HTML code for many subpages you'll do better if you use a **tag** instead of declaring `@sidebar` block in each view. Remember that tag is nothing more then just a scala view (template) and you can include it as any other view. Just create a normal **view** in `app/views/tags` i.e.: `sidebar.scala.html` with required HTML block, so you can later use it somewhere like:

```
<div class="span3">@tags.sidebar("content to pass")</div>
```

or as a block passed to higher level layout, etc :

```
@parent(tags.sidebar(additionalContent)){
    <div>Main content of the child view</div>
}
```

TBH I never knew what's the difference between including views and tags ;)

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit or just suggest me some useful links about how to use a `tag`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, views are just functions in play. You cannot inherit them, but you can easily define reusable blocks:

```
@parent() = {
    ...
}
```

And then reuse it anywhere:

```
<div ....sidebar>
  @parent()
</div>
```

The working example would look like this:

**base.scala.html**

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)
<html>
    <head><title>@title</title></head>
    <body>
        <div class=...>@content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.scala.html**

```
@(someParam: String)

@base("index") {
    <h1>@someParam</h1>
}
```

If you don't need your index page to share the base's behaviour - just don't use `@base`:

**index.scala.html**

```
@(someParam: String)

...some other content
@someParam
...more content
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

**parent.scala.html**

```
@(title: String)(content: (() => Html) => Html) {
<div class="parent">
  <h2>@title</h2>
  @content { () =>
    <p>This is the parents optional contribution to the sidebar.</p>
  }
</div>
```

**child.scala.html**

```
@parent("Some title") { parentSidebar =>
  <p>Blah blah blah.</p>
  <div class="sidebar">
    ...
    @parentSidebar()
  </div>
}
```

So the parent takes a function that takes a function that returns HTML.