# Add javascript to current view

Tags: playframework-2.2

Is there a way to add a script tag declared in view B to the list of scripts in view A (which calls B)? 
The example below should make it clear what I need.
I have a base template A:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
        <!-- declared stylesheets -->

    </head>
    <body>
        @content

        <!-- Java script dependencies -->
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that the base view declares dependencies to jquery.js and bootstrap.js at the end of the file. This is OK except for the following case:

```
@base(title) {
@header()
@navigation()
<div class="container">
    @content
</div>}
```

The `navigation` view has a script tag that depends on jquery already being loaded.
When I load the page I get an error stating that "$ symbol is not defined" which makes sense because the script is parsed before jquery is loaded.
Is there a way for me to add the script declared in `navigation` at the end of the base view (after the declaration of jquery)?

I've tried moving the dependency to jquery to the `<head></head>` section and everything works as expected, but I would like to keep the current layout.

Edit: **To be more clear, I want to send the script dependencies from @navigation view to @base view .**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to Play's doc for ***[moreScripts and moreStyles equivalents](http://playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaTemplateUseCases)*** (last section in doc)

De dacto it deosn't need to be named `scripts` so you can use your own name, also you can use it for sending other blocks of HTML into higher level view (layout).

**[See answers to similar quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22710748/1066240)**

So it can be i.e.:

```
@navigationScripts = {
    <script src="/assets/my-navigation.js"></script>
}

@base(title, navigationScripts) {
    @header()
    @navigation()
    <div class="container">
        @content
    </div>
}
```

And in layout:

```
@(title: String, navigationScripts: Html = null)
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
        <!-- declared stylesheets -->

    </head>
    <body>
        @content


        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        @navigationScripts
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok, I did read the documentation you've linked to, but I still have a question. If, for example, I have the following hierarchy BaseView->Complex View which invokes NavigationPartialView. Can I use this to send script dependencies from navigation to base view? The linked document is for the case when one view extends a base view.

Comment: You need to send it from _ComplexView_ to _BaseView_ because you don't pass params from _navigation_ to _complex_